# Detect scratches on the white Images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a data set that contains washing machine images with light and big deep scratches. I have tried the following two images with the the below-listed code.

**Side cropped and rotated image:**

[image: image_01]

**Side cropped image but not rotated:**

[image: image_02]

I have tried the following code from [How to improve the detection of the defect on the surface?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) but it is not working for white images which show black screens in the output. I have a huge data set of such images but am not able to detect the scratches. How could I do this using the following code? If it's not possible then what would be the right approach?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread('./detect-01.jpg')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# adaptive threshold 
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, -35)

# apply morphology
kernel = np.ones((3,30),np.uint8)
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
kernel = np.ones((3,35),np.uint8)
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# get hough line segments
threshold = 25
minLineLength = 10
maxLineGap = 20
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(morph, 1, 30*np.pi/360, threshold, minLineLength, maxLineGap)

# draw lines
linear1 = np.zeros_like(thresh)
linear2 = img.copy()
for [line] in lines:
    x1 = line[0]
    y1 = line[1]
    x2 = line[2]
    y2 = line[3]
    cv2.line(linear1, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), 255, 1)
    cv2.line(linear2, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0,0,255), 1)

print('number of lines:',len(lines))

# save resulting masked image
cv2.imwrite('scratches_thresh.jpg', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('scratches_morph.jpg', morph)
cv2.imwrite('scratches_lines1.jpg', linear1)
cv2.imwrite('scratches_lines2.jpg', linear2)

# display result
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("morph", morph)
cv2.imshow("lines1", linear1)
cv2.imshow("lines2", linear2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: discard all the low level image processing. just train a neural network for semantic segmentation. annotate the detects in your images, train it on that. -- I generally recommend that newbies stay away from canny and hough transforms. those algorithms have specific uses, and this does not look like one of them.

Comment: Thanks, @ChristophRackwitz, how can I annotate the images after semantic segmentation through the neural network? Then I have to train for scratches detection for example. right?

Answer (score 0):

I will provide you few suggestions based on my experience.

1. Get the Canny of the gray scale image.
2. Canny thresholds for the lighter background images should be less. For example threshold1: 20, threshold2: 35 etc.
3. For dark background images canny thresholds can be 150, 220 etc.
4. Apply the houghline on the canny output image.
5. Try to use Houghlines first instead of HoughlinesP.
6. Draw the detected lines on image and adjust the threshold values.